# What is the name of this part of my trunk release in my 2003 Jetta?

Tags: vw, part-identification

I can't open the trunk in my 2003 VW Jetta.  After taking apart the trunk hood, I've determined the problem is the same as described in [this thread](http://forums.tdiclub.com/showthread.php?t=81603), but I cannot find the replacement part.  This thread mentions a part number for the trunk latch, but the latch isn't what's broken... the part that's broken is the black plastic "arm" (pointed to in the photo by the caption 'Broken arm').

Searching Google and various parts web sites has not gotten me anywhere.  What is this part called?

[image: Broken trunk release 'arm']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I've found to this apparently common break, is not to replace the factory part at all, but instead to apply the 3rd party [Jetta Trunk Fix Kit](http://jettatrunk.com/) 3rd-party fix (US$40).

This kit comes with a piece that fits over the existing (broken) piece, along with a brace that is easily installed using just a screwdriver, making it not only cheaper than replacing with an OEM part, but also much easier.  It is also allegedly stronger than the OEM part (and from my observation of the broken part, and the replacement fix-it kit, I believe this claim).

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to tell from your picture but that appears to be a broken actuator or connector.

I did find you an exploded view of the trunk if that's not the correct part, though.  I searched at [Parts.com](http://www.parts.com/) for a 2003 Jetta and followed the trail to "Main Categories | Trunk lid | Lid and components | Actuator, Connector".  If you click on the [Image # 13](http://www.parts.com/oemcatalog/index.cfm?action=getPartLocator&siteid=2&chapter=&Sectionids=0,2822&groupid=51935&subgroupid=2378&componentid=4170&makeid=35&model=Jetta&year=2003&graphicID=9277660&callout=13&catalogid=2&displayCatalogid=0) link next to the part, it will bring up the exploded view with the numbered parts labelled.

Regardless, all of those parts appear to be user serviceable.  If you can deduce which actual part number you need, they seem to be in stock.  Good luck.

Comment: Nice exploded view... it looks like the actual broken part is part of #14, although hidden from view in that photo.  I'm sure I need to order the entire part 14, though, as I'd be surprised to find just the plastic lever available for sale separately.

Answer (score 1):

The part is the carrier plate aka jetta trunk bracket aka actuator bracket. The part number is 1J5827425E. Check ebay...Cheers